# Laravel output source controller, model and view file path in all view source?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I've taken over management of a large complex site with multiple laravel installations of various ages. Some are in use some are only partially so for some routes (complex htaccess redirects abound).

I'm new to Laravel so this is a bit of a headache for me.

Is there an easy way to have laravel include the source path and filename of the controller, model and view it has used when rendering a view so I can find what files on the server are responsible for what 'pages' on the site?

TY

Answer (score 1):

If you have a relative small site (i.e. a handfull of pages) you can visit each page with [Laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) activated. In my office we use this for a while now and we are pretty positive about it. There is a special 'views' tab that enables you to see which views are included when you visit a certain page. It has some nice options, you can even view queries!

Example from our development environment with `APP_DEBUG=true` in the `.env` file:

[image: Laravel debugbar views tab]

In addition to the debugbar, you can also consider a package that shows route information for you by listing all routes that are called and showing the names of controllers, methods and request type in an other colour. We use [Pretty routes](https://github.com/garygreen/pretty-routes) since it is more convenient for us to read all 'routes' in the browser than in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

When starting from the `app/` directory, the path of any of these classes is the same as the namespace they are in. 
So if you have a model `App\Models\User`, this will be located in `app/models/User.php`.

As for the views, you start in the `resources/views/` directory, replace dots in the view name by `/` and add `.blade.php`.
So, a view named `website.index` is located in `resources/views/website/index.blade.php`.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an advanced answer that requires some Linux skills, but with the built in commando `strace` you can see which resources are opened: which php file, which database calls etc. This way you can analyze what is used when.

A very good tutorial can be found here: 
https://hackernoon.com/debugging-a-php-application-with-strace-4d0ae59f880b

another great article on strace with PHP: https://ma.ttias.be/linux-application-script-debugging-with-strace/

I would also suggest to use all kind of filters and grep to filter the output to something meaningful.